# Why Mojolicious route parameter is not rendered?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have route with default capture value:

```
my $api =  $r->under( '/api/v:api', [ api => qr/\d+/ ], { api => 1 } )->name( 'api' );
```

When I `render` this route I get `/api/v`:

```
$api->render; # /api/v
```

It is OK, but when I want to force version rendering it is not rendered:

```
$api->render({ api => 1 }); # RESULT: /api/v EXPECT: /api/v1
```

I am not expect this even that 1 is equal to default value

Why Mojolicious route parameter is not rendered when I force it to be?

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [Routing Guide](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Standard-placeholders) when you want to intermix text and placeholders in the same path segment (between slashes) you need to surround the placeholder with parentheses.

```
$r->under('/api/v(:api)', ...)
```

should work, although, it goes further to say that once you have the parentheses form you can omit the `:` so

```
$r->under('/api/v(api)', ...)
```

should work too.

Comment: You are not right. Parentheses has no any matter here. The problem is [here](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-7.28/lib/Mojolicious/Routes/Pattern.pm#L72). You should check if palaceholder value is forced to be rendered by doing next check also: `|| defined $values->{$value}`

Comment: Despite on this fix cause tests to fail we do it. Because that bug cause more serious problems with caching. Imagine we have `/api/v1/index.html` because of version is not rendered the image on this page will be rendered as `/api/v/image.jpg`. When next time we upgrade backend and implement version 2. The application will make query to `/api/v2/index.html` but image link will be `/api/v/image.jpg` still. Thus causing to display image version 1 instead of expected version 2.

Comment: Even in case of request `/api/v` had come we are expecting `/api/v1/image.jpg` is rendered

Comment: I can't replicate your render problem: `perl -Mojo -E 'my $r = app->routes; my $api = $r->any("/api/v(:api)"); say $api->render({api => 1})'` (and all variants for the pattern) work for me.

Comment: You should provide default value: `$r->any( "/api/v(:api)", { api => 1 } )`

Comment: Ok that finally does replicate the issue `perl -Mojo -E 'my $r = app->routes; my $api = $r->any("/api/v(:api)", {api => 1}); say $api->render({api => 1})'` this may be a bug (I haven't discussed on IRC yet).

Comment: Well, there are two ways to look at this, strictly it isn't what you asked for, but from the router's point of view it is an equivalent url.

Comment: I think of them as next. For both requests `/api/v` and `/api/v1` are equal if default is `{api=>1}`. And both should dispatch one action. But when this route is rendered it should be full `/api/v1` and not the `/api/v` because they are different and lead to caching problems described above.

Comment: `>this may be a bug (I haven't discussed on IRC yet)` Did you discuss this on IRC?